# Maui app .NET isn't showing on simulator ios

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I've been flowing this link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Then I conntected to Mac successfully.

when i run the app, it is not showing on the simulator.
see image below
[image: simulator ios].

I don't know what is going on.
Does anyone have this issue before?
Help me please.

Comment: Check the application build logs, post them here

Comment: Can you provide some build logs or error messages?

Comment: If found that building the project before hitting the run button helps when I have simulator deployment issues. Also make sure you are running XCode 14.1

Comment: thanks, i updated Xcode to 14.2, it works